# Logarithms and Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

A multiple choice question asked the for the value of $\log_m(\sin x)$ given $\log_m(\cos x)=n$ where $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both positive and $m>1$. It is easily seen that the correct answer is $\cfrac{1}{2}\log_m(1-m^{2n})$. I was wondering if anyone could think of a possible extension to this short problem? I experimented with formulae for $\log_m(\tan x)$, $\log_m(\sin 2x)$ etc. but nothing interesting stood out.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_m(\cos x) = n \Rightarrow  m^n = \cos x$$
$$m^{2n} + \sin^2 x = 1 \Rightarrow \sin x = \sqrt{1- m^{2n}} \Rightarrow \log_m(\sin x) = {1\over2}\log_m(1-m^{2n})$$

---

### $\sin 2x$

let  $\log_m(2) = k$

$$\log_m(\cos x) + \log_m(\sin x) +  \log_m(2) = n + {1\over2}\log_m(1-m^{2n}) + k$$
$$\log_m(\sin 2x) = n + {1\over2}\log_m(1-m^{2n}) + k$$

---

### $\tan x$

$${\log_m(\sin x) -  \log_m(\cos x)} = {1\over2}\log_m(1-m^{2n}) - n$$
$$\log_m(\tan x) = {1\over2}\log_m(1-m^{2n}) - n$$

are these interesting or not ?